# Is it possible to load a java type from xml

Tags: java, class, dynamic, loading

To put this in different angle with an example...

I define class properties in a xml file (almost just like hbm file)
for example

```
<class name="my.package.Employee">
<prop name="ename" type="string"> <<legth of string in xml format>> </prop>
<prop name="dob" type="date"/> 
</class>
```

in my java code i should be able to use this class directly.

```
import my.package;

method1(){
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.name = "My Name";
    e.dob = "04/02/2000";
}
```

My Actual question is: **How to tell the JVM to load/form a java class/Type from different formats rather just from '.java' file.**

-- the below thing is just an idea for future.

Today i explained it in XML format. might be tomorrow i write an interpreter to understand the class defination from text paragraph.

*"Each Company has recrutes many employees. where each employee has name and age. name use to be maximum of 50 letters and age would be calculated based on the date of birth."*

with this text the JVM should load Company class and Employee class.

Company class should have a list/set property and corresponding getters for employees. 
Employee class should have name, dob properties and age, but age is calculated.

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve your problem with code generation: you can either generate and compile at runtime or at build time.

Essentially you read your description file (be it an xml, or a natural-language description) and write a .java file containing all the code that define you class. 
Something like it is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660332/349620)

Answer (score 1):

**How to tell the JVM to load/form a java class/Type from different formats rather just from '.java' file.**

It's actually a class file and you can't.
You have several tools which can generate Java source files out of XML schema files such as [xjc compiler](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html)