# Java interpreter code at runtime

Tags: java

We have discussed how java is first compiled into Java bytecode and then interpreted by the JVM. Build into the program we are using (Dr Java), there is a panel called Interactions where you can type code in real time and have it be interpreted and ran (I believe that is how it works). I was wondering if it was possible to have a compiled program in java be ran, and then allow a user to input java code to be interpreted to modify the things that happen. I can't really think of any practical uses of this, but here is an example to clarify:

User runs a program and an integer in initialized with the value of 2 and the name of changeNumber. A pop-up comes up allowing the user to input some java code. They can input something like - "changeNumber = changeNumber + 2;" and have the code execute in real time where if you ended up printing out changeNumber, you would get 4.

Comment: The simplest answer that comes into my mind is: take a look at **Groovy**: http://groovy.codehaus.org/. It's a Java language extension which inherently allows what you are looking for.

Comment: Some debuggers will allow you to update some values.

Comment: Sure, parse the input and add a touch of reflection. I wouldn't advise you to look into this just yet though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Runtime code generation and compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064226/runtime-code-generation-and-compilation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the [Reflection API.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

As a side note, I do not understand the downvotes. This is a good and well-written question for a beginner.

Comment: Personally, I have downvoted this question because it lacks any research effort -- there are tons of resources in the internet on the topic, e.g. **first result** in google with query *java runtime code* leads [to this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064226/runtime-code-generation-and-compilation)